# Spotify Multiple Genre Classification

Tags: python, spotipy

I am working with the Spotify API in Python and it is returning multiple genres. I am trying to figure out a way to pull the primary genre. Example, the genres brought in our blues, Chicago blues, rythm and blues. I am able to pick out the first one listed and return it in a new column by using the .split method. The issue I am running into now is finding a more efficient way to rename these genres into broader categories (Rock, Blues, etc...)

```
# Created function to return first genre in list.
d`ef get_first_genre(genre_list):
    return genre_list.split(',')[0].strip()`

**# Create a new column "Sub Category" that holds the first genre**
fifties_df['Sub Category'] = fifties_df['Genres'].apply(get_first_genre)

**your text**# Created a new column "Main Genre" that renames the sub category genre into a broader genre category (ex. rockabilly into Rock) by using this method below.

fifties_df.loc[fifties_df['Sub Category'] == 'doo-wop', 'Main Genre'] ='R&B'
fifties_df.loc[fifties_df['Sub Category'] == 'blues', 'Main Genre'] ='Blues'``
fifties_df.loc[fifties_df['Sub Category'] == 'jazz organ', 'Main Genre'] ='Jazz'
fifties_df.loc[fifties_df['Sub Category'] == 'rock-and-roll', 'Main Genre'] ='Rock'
fifties_df.loc[fifties_df['Sub Category'] == 'adult standards', 'Main Genre'] ='Pop'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with if-else and apply in Sub category column

```
def get_broad_category(sub_category):
    if sub_category == 'rock-and-roll':
        return "Rock"
    elif sub_category == 'blues'
        return "Blues"

fifties_df['Category'] = fifties_df['Sub Category'].apply(get_broad_category)
```

Comment: My thinking is that I would still have to include all the sub category genres which would make the function just as long. Is it possible to do this with a function (if the genre was "orleans blues') using something like if sub_category.contains('blues') return "Blues"?

Comment: np.select can be used to add multiple conditions similar to method
conditions = [
        ( fifties_df['Sub Category'].str.contains('Rock')),
         (fifties_df['Sub Category'].isin(['Mel', 'adult standards']))
       ] 
choices = ['Rock', 'Pop']
fifties_df['New Category']=  np.select(conditions, choices, default='unknown')